# ASP.net.MVC 5 create a page which will display sql query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to learn how can I add to my controller some SQL query but I don't know how to do it properly.

My controller is

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(db.Student.ToList());
}
```

By default page is giving me the next data.

```
   ID,  NAME,  STATUS
    1   Bella,  5
    2   Bella,  5
    3   Bella,  7
```

I want to add the next SQL query to the controller which will give me data that I want it on page to display.

```
(select distinct id,name,max(status) from students group by id,name)



ID,  NAME,  STATUS

    3   Bella,  7
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, do you want to filter your data?

Comment: I first example 3 rows i want only one row which with max(status). So my page will display to users only one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a linq with a group-by clause as below;

```html
var students = from s in db.Student
               group s by s.name into groupedResult
               select new 
               {
                  Name = groupedResult.Key,
                  Max_Status = groupedResult.Max(g => g.Status)
               } ;
```

Comment: i did next  var students = from s in db.Univet
                           group s by s.Name into groupedResult
                           select new
                           {
                               Name = groupedResult.Key,
                               Max_Status = groupedResult.Max(g => g.Status)
                           };

            return View();

Comment: yes it working thank you, but where i need to add "Dinstinct" to avoid values which is repeatedly inserted to table

Comment: like in my sql query

Comment: is it correct return which i'm using ? "  return View(db.Univet.ToList()); "

Comment: Happy to be of help.
You don't need DISTINCT because group-by takes care of that by ensuring rows are not repeated

Comment: no i need it, because there logic is next ( " name ="Ben"; status ="1" ) it's been inserted 1 year ago and this row is needed to display, after some time user inserting another row with the same name = "Ben" but another status ="2"

Comment: so in a page should display next data ( name ="Ben" status="2" ) only one row

Comment: I see. 
If that is the case, GROUPING might not be the problem but PAGINATION.
You should write your return statement like this 
" return View(db.Univet.ToPagedList(pageNumber, numberOfRowsToDisplay)); "

Comment: Why is there ToPagedList ?

Comment: I mean i did not implemented this, or i need ? ( he will give me error "because its not exist in context")

Comment: at this moment im using the next return "return View(db.Univet.ToList());"

Comment: and query in controller doesnt work ( may be there need of DINSTINCT ?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174256/discussion-between-christian-nwafor-and-white-fang).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group data by `Name` and display Maximum value of `Status` with linq then you can do as below.

```
var students = db.Student.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                      .Select(g => new Student()
                        {
                            Name = g.Key,
                            Status = g.Max(row => row.Status),
                            Id = g.Max(row => row.Id)
                        }).ToList();
return View(students);
```

Comment: Name = g.Key - What does it mean ?

Comment: `Name = g.Key` this will give you  value of `Name` property on which GroupBy is performed.

Comment: Added `Id` in code. Hopefully this might solve your problem.

Comment: The entity or complex type 'Tessa.Models.Univet' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The entity or complex type 'Tessa.Models.Univet' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.